# JS - Inject content of textarea into multiple text areas which share a class

Tags: javascript, textarea

Scenario:
I have a series of textareas with the class "title".
On the same document, I have a separate textarea with the class "setter".

I need to make a button that will replace the content of all textareas that have the class "title" with the current content of the textarea that has the class name "setter" at the moment the button is clicked.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know JS, so I'm a bit emabrassed to show you the sloppy piece of code I put together from about a donzen different posts, but here it is:
`jQuery(function ($) {
      function() {
              var Title = document.getElementbyId('newalbum').val ;
              document.getElementByClassName('title').val = Title ;
               
      };
      });`

Comment: If you don't know JS, I would say that you should start by learning jQuery. It's an excellent framework that abstracts JavaScript code for you. http://www.jquery.com.

Comment: Thanks, I started learning and practising online about a week ago, so I still run into a lot of bumps. This website helps me a great deal coming to a functioning solution that then I can dissect to better understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and reference jQuery

```
$("#MyButtonID").click(function() { 
    $(".title").val($(".setter").val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Jquery to solve the problem like this

```
$("textarea[class='setter']").val("your text"));
```

this should be in the onclick of the buttom

Comment: This is not optimized. jQuery has a selector for classes and it's the "." operator

Comment: But you get only the textarea for find the class, I suppose that the textareas aren't a lot

Comment: I understand what you wanna mean. I change the answer

Answer (score 2):

I made a quick JS fiddle example how you can do it with just pure javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yazpj/883/

```
...
    var doc = document,
        theTitles = doc.querySelectorAll( '.title' ),
        theValue = doc.getElementById( 'the-setter' ).value;

    for( var i=0,titleLen=theTitles.length; i<titleLen; i++ ) {

        theTitles[i].value = theValue;

    }
...
```